# pipe message in c being truncated

Tags: c, string, pipe, strlen

I wrote a simple program to learn how to write pipe messages in C, and while doing it I found something rather strange which i can't explain or understand, this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSIZE 100
int fd[2];

void writeMsg() {
    int i;
    char message[MAXSIZE];
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        sprintf(message,"%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n",i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i);
        write(fd[1], message, strlen(message));
    }
}

int main() {
    pipe(fd);
    char message[MAXSIZE];
    int pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        writeMsg();
    }
    if (pid > 10) {
        wait(NULL);
        read(fd[0], message, MAXSIZE);
        printf("%s", message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In writeMsg there's a loop to write a message bigger than MAXSIZE in the pipe, after that the message is read and printed in main, the strange thing is, if I use `strlen(message)` in `write(fd[1], message, strlen(message))` the following message is printed:

```
0000000000
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
4444444444
5555555555
6666666666
7777777777
8888888888
9
```

But if instead i use `write(fd[1], message, strlen(message)+1)` the message is:

```
0000000000
```

What is the difference between `strlen(message)` and `strlen(message)+1` ?  In here http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:write it is said that if the number of bytes to write are smaller than the provided buffer, the output is truncated, but with +1 the string size is 11, which is not greater than MAXSIZE. 
Any clarification or corrections are welcome.

Comment: You probably want to call `read` in a loop and check the return value, until nothing more can be read. And/or set MAXSIZE a little bigger...

Comment: The aim of the question was to understand what is the difference that +1 in the strlen makes. If read is called in a loop the number of iterations (or messages written) would have to been known beforehand,wouldn't?

Comment: Why are you refusing to perform the read operation if the parent's PID is less than ten? I understand that `pid==0` is going to be the child of the fork, and you'll never get `pid==1` because that's the init process, but what's special about pids `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, and `9`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The +1 will cause the zero at the end of the string (after the newline) to be transmitted, which means that when you print the buffer on the other end, `printf` stops after the first line. You don't really want to send that zero, I think, so don't do that...

If you really want the zero at the end of the string through the pipe, you will have to then figure out where each string ends, and print them individually, e.g. using `strlen()` to figure out how long the message is, and use an index that moves `index += strlen(&message[index])+1`, and `printf("%s", &message[index]);` in a loop until you have printed all (compared index with how much you've read!).

Using a loop until `read` returns zero bytes should allow you to read all the input (you are reading too short right now, that's why you're not getting all the 9's).

Comment: Hmm, didn't realize that, thanks for the the answer and the suggestion Mats Petersson.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that when calling `write` with `strlen(message) + 1` the `\0` character is also written.

That means that, when `read()`ing, the `\0` will be appended to your char's array. Since `printf()` stops when it finds `\0`, this is the reason why the only printed text in what was written by your first call to `write()`.